# react-navigation: Detect when screen, tabbar is activated / appear / focus / blur

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, onfocus, viewdidappear

Perviously when I wanted to make some actions when screen is opened I put them inside `componentDidMount`. For example I can fetch some data.

like this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.updateData();
}
```

But with `react-navigation` **`componentDidMount`** occurs only one time when user open screen first time, and if later user open this page again it will not trigger componentDidMount.

What is proper way to detect when page(screen) is activated and do actions?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

### React navigation v6

**Fetching data with an API call when a screen becomes focused**

> React Navigation provides a hook that runs an effect when the screen comes into focus and cleans it up when it goes out of focus. This is useful for cases such as adding event listeners, for fetching data with an API call when a screen becomes focused, or any other action that needs to happen once the screen comes into view.

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function ProfileScreen() {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {

      alert('Screen was focused');

      return () => {

        alert('Screen was unfocused');
        // Useful for cleanup functions

      };
    }, [])
  );

  return <View />;
}
```

**A boolean indicating whether the screen is focused or not**

> React Navigation provides a hook that returns a boolean indicating whether the screen is focused or not.
> The hook will return true when the screen is focused and false when our component is no longer focused. This enables us to render something conditionally based on whether the user is on the screen or not.

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Text>{isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>;
}
```

Ref v6.x: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

---

Older:

With `react-navigation`, you can do that in 2 steps:

1. Add listeners in `componentDidMount`or `componentWillMount`, to hook events
2. Remove listeners in `componentWillUnmount` , to avoid unexpected calling

### API Reference Documents v3.x, v4.x, v5.x

**React-navigation v3.x, v4.x**:

> `addListener` - Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle
>
> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
> them:
>
> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

**React-navigation 3.x, 4.x** example:

```
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didBlur',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didBlur', payload);
  }
);

// Remove the listener when you are done
didBlurSubscription.remove();
```

Ref v4.x https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-prop/#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

**UPDATED v5.x**

The events had been changed in v5.x

> Screens can add listeners on the
> navigation prop like in React Navigation. By default, there are 2
> events available:
>
> - focus - This event is emitted when the screen comes into focus
> - blur - This event is emitted when the screen goes out of focus
> - state (advanced) - This event is emitted when the navigator's state changes

Sample code from reactnavigation.org

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    // Content of the component
  }
}
```

Use with hook

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <ProfileContent />;
}
```

Listeners prop on Screen

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    tabPress: e => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do something with the `navigation` object
      navigation.navigate('AnotherPlace');
    },
  })}
/>
```

Ref v5.x: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events

Comment: I do this. But it only calls once. when I go to another app and came to my app I need to call function again. What should I do?

Comment: Opening app from background won't invoke `didFocus`. You should use `    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);`.

Comment: How do you remove listener on version 5.x?

Comment: willFocus, didFocus, willBlur & didBlur how to achieve this with react-navigation v5?

Comment: As their documents, v5.x has `focus` and `blur` event. For `will`, `did` event, you can try `state (advanced)`

Comment: WOW I did not know these hooks existed and I have built quite a few front ends with React Navigation V6, these are super useful in certain situations, much better dev experience than using event listeners in a use effect hook.

Answer (score 15):

**FOR V3.x and V4.x**
This might be late but this is how I solved it.
See the code below. Don't forget to import withNavigation and wrap your export default withNavigation.

```
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
 componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Remove the event listener
    this.focusListener.remove();
  }

export default withNavigation(Your Class Name);
```

**FOR V5.x Please use this.**

```
 componentDidMount(){
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {      
    // Call ur function here.. or add logic.     
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't work like you described it (for v5). There seems not to be any  `didFocus` event. See here for detail information: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#navigationaddlistener. So https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290888/1256697 is the right answer here.

Comment: Hi this worked for v3 and v4 but for v5 am using this. Alot of things changed in v5 so you might want to make the Documentation your friend.
`const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
     // Call ur function here.. or add logic.
    });`

Comment: Yep, I know how it works (because I'm currently working with v5), but I add the comment for other users so that they can save some time. Would be fine, if you edit your post and write it inside, that you're answer depend on v3 & v4

Comment: @suther i have updated my answer, Thanx for the concern.

Answer (score 8):

`componentDidMount` / `componentWillUnmount` does not work in all cases of navigation (like tabs).

You need to use `addListener` with events **didFocus** and **didBlur** to make such actions. See [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) for details

Answer (score 7):

The latest version of `react-navigation` provides custom hooks that let you react to focus and blur events: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen.

The following is an example from their docs that uses the `onFocusEffect` hook to make an API call on focus (it cleans up the effect when the screen goes out of focus):

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(data));

      return unsubscribe;
    }, [userId])
  );

  return <ProfileContent user={user} />;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`NavigationEvents` is another way to add event listener just inside JSX. See [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) for details.

It looks something like this:

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    <NavigationEvents            
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur', payload)}
    />
    {this.props.children}
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: You should also mention that it will not work with react-navigation v5.

Answer (score 0):

in **react navigation 6** all you need to do is

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
function Profile() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Text>{isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>;
}
```

[refer docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused)