# How to add subscriptions on defaultNavigationOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50290888/9816472), trying to subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle

> Navigator.js

```js
const App = createStackNavigator(
  {
    screen1: { screen: MainScreen },
    screen2: { screen: SecondaryScreen },
  },
  {
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(App);

export default MainNavigator;
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to subscribe to events in this `navigator` file? Or I have no other options but to subscribe at each and every individual screens?

Answer (score 0):

you can add listener for each screen like this

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.navigation.addListener(
            'willFocus',//event name
            payload => {
                //do your work here
            }
        );
    }
```

**other event names**:`'onDidFocus', 'onWillBlur' ,'onDidBlur'`

[reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to subscribe to events in this navigator file? Or I have no other options but to subscribe at each and every individual screens?